# Can't get iframe.contentwindow/postmessage to work because permission is denied within same domain

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, iframe, msdn, postmessage

I can't get the simplest iframe contentwindow code to work because permission to the contentwindow is always denied. After getting to the WTF stage with my own code every which way, I isolated my attempts down and in the example below I use only Microsoft's own sample code from its very own documentation of iframe contentwindow from MSDN help. MSDN's code has the same problem! (Actually it has two problems but I fixed its use of ="iframe" to ="IFRAME" because "iframe" != "IFRAME".)

I am developing in Visual Studio Community 2015 using the Javascript-Windows 8-Windows template.

In debugging, I see that whenever I use the iframeid.contentwindow construct, I get permission denied as shown in the screen shot at the end of this post.

Here's my code:

1) default.html: (straight from the documentation and pasted into VS)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App3</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet"                         />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

     <!-- App3 references --        >
     <link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
          function fnNavigate() {
                for (i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++) {
          if (document.all(i).tagName == "IFRAME") {
            document.all(i).contentWindow.location = "http://www.msn.com";
          }
        }
      }
     </script>
     <script src="/js/default.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <p> start
    <button onclick="fnNavigate();">Navigate Frames</button>
    <p>
    <iframe src="http://www.microsoft.com" style="width:100%;height:150px;">                         </iframe>
    <p />
    <iframe src="http://www.microsoft.com" style="width:100%;height:150px;"></iframe>
     <p />
     <iframe src="http://www.microsoft.com" style="width:100%;height:150px;"></iframe>
     <p /> end 
</body>
</html>
```

and 2) default.js -- unchanged from what VS template generates out of the box

```
    (function () {
        "use strict";

        var app = WinJS.Application;
        var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

        app.onactivated = function (args) {
            if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
                if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !==         activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application was suspended and then terminated.
            // To create a smooth user experience, restore application state         here so that it looks like the app never stopped running.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

        app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
            // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
            // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
            // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
            // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
            // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
            // args.setPromise().
        };

        app.start();
    })();
```

Despite finding several seemingly similar posts, I have found nothing that helps. Many posts discuss AJAX, crossdomain origins, CORS, browser support for iFrames... -- I have none of that complexity. I am only running this in VS debugger right now and intend to use the code that way as a 1-tier local app or deployed for local IIS/Chrome use. I have a feeling that either it's never possible to access an iframe's contentwindow or I am missing something simple. I suspect it's the latter. If you know the answer, I would appreciate the help. ;>)
Thanks

[Screen shot of Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpgsd.png)

Comment: Did you make it work in the end ?